# Adding new user to xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been working on a new iOS application of mine for about 6 months. I am bringing another individual to help me with my project and this is the first time I will be doing a joint project.

My question is this, is there someway to protect my code from this individual stealing it or trying to use it themselves? I trust the individual but I do not want to take any chances.
I know apple offers ad-hoc but I thought that was just for testing purposes once the application is finished?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **stealing it or trying to use it themselves**. What work does the other person on your project do? Code? Graphics?

Comment: Sounds like you don't really trust the person deep down inside if you are having these fears.

Comment: The simple as no. You can't protect the code at all if you want the user to be able to do builds and test the app during development. You either trust them or you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guys can work together using Subversion. You have to configure Xcode to use Subversion.

Please see the details [here](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/03/configuring-xcode-to-use-subversion/)

Step 1. **Tell Xcode about your repository.**

Step 2. **Let’s put your code on the Subversion server**

Step 3. **Both Guys Check-out your newly imported code from the repository**

Step 4. **Inform your Project that it is under SCM control**

Comment: Thanks but then it is obvious to the other person I dont trust them :)

Comment: then better to leave them.. lol... what kind of the work they are going to do in ur project ?

Comment: @Teddy13 How is the use of Subversion a hint that you don't trust the person. The lack of Subversion means you don't know how to do proper app development. Even a single person project should be using Subversion or Git.

Comment: @maddy I came here looking for support. If you want to get personal and accuse me of not knowing proper app development then I suggest you take a hard look at your life since you need to use stackoverflow to feel "powerful"

Comment: @Ramshad Thank you Ramshad, I will use this solution

Comment: @Ramshad Sorry last question, where can I download subversion?

Comment: @Teddy13:Contact ur network admin,, and set-up a SVN repository for your project. Checkout the project using SCM tool in Xcode.

Comment: Very weird.. This has nothing to do with the question "Protecting the code from being being abused by the other contributor"

Comment: @Teddy13 it appears you took my comment the wrong way. I did not intend to insult you. You claimed that using source control would be an indication of mistrust. I was trying to point out that using source control is normal. No one would see it's use as mistrust.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is no, if the other guy has the code, he can "steal" it. There is copyright, and you can probably workout a legal agreement, but that probably isn't what you want. If you have a large part of your application running on a server then that is "safe". You do not have to share the entire code with him depending on how much you want him to contribute. Ad Hoc builds are for testing as you said, not development.

Comment: Thank you. IS there some way to code sign so he cannot submit?

Comment: No. He has the code, he can change any code-signing settings.